# Django progress bar update by view

Tags: django, loops, while-loop, return, progress-bar

I have a progress bar in my html, I want to send the percentage from a view function and so update it. I should use a while in the view function but to pass the variable to html I should use:

```
return render(request, 'Progress.html', {'ProgressBar':ProgressBarPercentage})
```

this will break the while loop, How should I pass the variable to the html without returning?

Comment: Do you want to constantly update it?

Comment: For a limited amount. I can use a for also

Comment: This will trigger a page reload. I would look into something like this. https://buildwithdjango.com/blog/post/celery-progress-bars/

There are also a few packages out: https://github.com/robgolding/django-celery-progress

Comment: I was working on it since then, and this helped me: https://github.com/sunshineatnoon/Django-Celery-Example